# Is it possible to automatically validate RestController (via Spring MVC) methods response?

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

We can validate input parameters via `@Valid` annotation before any param, like this:

```
@RestController // new spring 4 annotation
public class ApplicationServiceApiV1Controller {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/response")
    public SomeResponse getResponse(@Valid SampleInputParam request) {
        return new SomeResponse();
    }
}
```

SampleInputParam own fields can be annotated with any javax.validation.constraints.* annotation and those values will be validated. If validation fail, client receives 400 or 406 http status. Is it possible to validate response as described above? I didn't find that usages with spring-mvc.

Comment: No, you will need to write and register your own `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` to do it.